# Should capped collection or collection with TTL indexes still be compacted regularly?

Tags: mongodb, performance, database, nosql

We have a write heavy workflow which handling with mongodb. And we often delete big portions of data. Because mongodb do not really delete data unless you invoke `compact` operation we sometimes faced with disk memory problems.

So my question is the following - If i will use TTL indexes or capped collections - I still need to invoke 'compact' operation to clean the space for real or it will be handle this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For capped collection compact is meaningless because the collection is of fixed size. Also taking natural order into mind, documents in a capped collection don't move, have no padding and can't grow in size (in fact such operations where documents may grow will fail), hence there is no fragmentation.

For collection with TTL index, no problem. In fact more fragmentation can be expected in such collections.

Comment: So for collections with TTL index compacting still necessary, right?

Comment: Yes, in fact it's more pressing to compact collections with TTL index if these are inserted often, and documents are deleted after a while.